# Is using a switch/case statement feasible here

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to revise my javascript file and eliminate any unnecessary stuff.  Right now, it looks pretty horrific (or at least I think it does).

I was wondering if it would be a good idea to use a `switch` statement with several `cases` - but to be quite honest, I wouldn't even know where to begin or how to write the necessary code.

I know the basic syntax for it but wouldn't know how to apply it in this case scenario.

```
switch () {
    case '':
        // code here
        break;
    case '':
        // code here
        break;
    default '':
        // code here
        break;
}
```

Or would it be more feasible to write this a completely different way.

Anyway, this is what I currently have on my js file...

JS:

```
$('a.screenshots_1').click(function() {
    $('.t_1, .t_2, .t_3, .t_4, .t_5, .t_6, .t_7, .t_8, .t_9, .t_10, .t_11, .t_12, .t_13, .t_14, .t_15, .t_16, .t_17, .t_18, .t_19, .t_20, .t_21, .t_22, .t_23, .t_24').hide();
    $('#main-overlay, .t_1').show();

    return false;
});
```

I have a total of 24  of these on this file...and feel like it could be drastically shortened...I just don't know how I would go about doing this.

```
$('a.screenshots_2').click(function() {
    $('.t_1, .t_2, .t_3, .t_4, .t_5, .t_6, .t_7, .t_8, .t_9, .t_10, .t_11, .t_12, .t_13, .t_14, .t_15, .t_16, .t_17, .t_18, .t_19, .t_20, .t_21, .t_22, .t_23, .t_24').hide();
    $('#main-overlay, .t_2').show();

    return false;
});
```

As you can see, `a.screenshots_#` and `$('#main-overlay, .t_#).show();` changes resepctively - where # is a number (listed from 1 - 24)

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ys4edLvf/) as requested.

**2nd Update:**

All I am looking to do here is to simplify my js file.  I have a total of 24 instances (or cases) and I'd like to see if I can get it down to 1 instance (or case) but apply to all 24...Hopefully that makes sense.  In a nuttshell, I'm trying to write cleaner code from what I have (if it's possible) and without adding anything additional (if able to) on my html/css files.

I'm considering this to be 1 instance:

```
$('a.screenshots_1').click(function() {
        $('.t_1, .t_2, .t_3, .t_4, .t_5, .t_6, .t_7, .t_8, .t_9, .t_10, .t_11, .t_12, .t_13, .t_14, .t_15, .t_16, .t_17, .t_18, .t_19, .t_20, .t_21, .t_22, .t_23, .t_24').hide();
        $('#main-overlay, .t_1').show();

        return false;
    });
```

and this to be the second instance:

```
$('a.screenshots_2').click(function() {
        $('.t_1, .t_2, .t_3, .t_4, .t_5, .t_6, .t_7, .t_8, .t_9, .t_10, .t_11, .t_12, .t_13, .t_14, .t_15, .t_16, .t_17, .t_18, .t_19, .t_20, .t_21, .t_22, .t_23, .t_24').hide();
        $('#main-overlay, .t_2').show();

        return false;
    });
```

and so forth...

Comment: Add a class common to all of them.

Comment: Create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate your script.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Just showing/hiding all of those elements when `a.screenshots_1` or `a.screenshots_2` are clicked?

Comment: @jeffdill2, In a nuttshell, I'd like to eliminate as much unnecessary stuff as possible.  I created a fiddle as a demonstration of how long this file is and I feel like it could be shortened up quite a bit.  The fiddle is added to my original post.

Comment: @Michael eliminating code is fine but again, what are you actually trying to accomplish - i.e. what do you want your code to *do*? Just layman terms for what you want to happen.

Comment: @jeffdill2, As you can see, I have 24 instances - I'm looking to see if there is a way to only have 1 instance - does that make sense?

Comment: I'm considering this to be 1 instance: `$('a.screenshots_1').click(function() {$('.t_1, .t_2, .t_3, .t_4, .t_5, .t_6, .t_7, .t_8, .t_9, .t_10, .t_11, .t_12, .t_13, .t_14, .t_15, .t_16, .t_17, .t_18, .t_19, .t_20, .t_21, .t_22, .t_23, .t_24').hide();$('#main-overlay, .t_1').show();return false;
});` And then this to be a second instance: `$('a.screenshots_2').click(function() {$('.t_1, .t_2, .t_3, .t_4, .t_5, .t_6, .t_7, .t_8, .t_9, .t_10, .t_11, .t_12, .t_13, .t_14, .t_15, .t_16, .t_17, .t_18, .t_19, .t_20, .t_21, .t_22, .t_23, .t_24').hide();$('#main-overlay, .t_2').show();return false;});`

Comment: I'm not looking to change anything function wise, I'm just looking to see if there is a way to write cleaner (or more efficient) code from what I currently have...

Answer (score 0):

Your tags `$('.t_1, .t_2, .t_3, .t_4, .t_5, .t_6)` etc. could have the same class ( let's say .toBeHidden ) and your `$('a.screenshots_1'), $('a.screenshots_2'), $('a.screenshots_3')`etc. also one same class ( let's say .screenshot ) so you could rewrite your code like that

```
$('screenshot').click(function() {
    $('.toBeHidden').hide();
    $('#main-overlay, .t_2').show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: that's not a bad idea, however, i'd still have 24 cases of it...since I'd have to change the `.show()` line for each.  I'm looking for a more practical approach if there is one

Comment: @Michael simply add a unique attribute to each `screenshots_#` element like `data-num="#"`, then in jQuery you could get that with `$(this).data('num')` to then show the correct element by interpolating that ID in your selector call `$('#main-overlay, t_' + $(this).data('num')).show()`

Comment: @Michael what do you mean you'd have to change the `.show()` for each one? In the example that Jorel has here, the one line `$('.toBeHidden').hide()` would take care of all 24 elements, if you gave all of them the `toBeHidden` class. Subsequently, you could do the same thing with show - `$('.toBeHidden').show()` would show all 24 elements that have that class.

Comment: @Michael well it would work for the 24th instance of your classes cause you'll give them all one extra class called toBeHidden. Therefore the selector $('.toBeHidden') will target those 24 elements, as long as they got the class toBeHidden

Comment: I understand that, but aside from that I'm looking for even a more simplified answer...Please re-read my 2nd update and let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: @Michael i've edited the code, now it should work for everything. Replace your whole js with mine, add the class toBeHidden on everything you want to hide and the class screenshot on everything you want to put a onClick listener

Comment: I think your missing the point of what I'm asking here...what you have done is for only 1 out of 24 instances...In other words, if I add what you have, not only would I have to add additional classes to my html file, I would have to write another 23 instances in my js file in order to show `.t_1`, `.t_3`, etc....This would not be ideal at all - it would be adding more overall rather than simplifying things.

Comment: No it would'nt. You clearly doesnt undestand code, and have absolutely extremely low and limited knowledge of JS, jquery, and css selector, which i don't mind, although it's a bit frustrating. If you don't get this basic code i don't think i can nor want to help you any further. You've received enough help from the SO community to be able to work something. Good luck tho.

Comment: This line here `$('#main-overlay, .t_2').show();` is what I'm referring too in what you provided.  I'd have to write your entire block of code 23 more times in my js file changing the `.t_2` on that specific line to `.t_1`, `.t_3`, `.t_4`, etc...So in other words, I'd still have 24 instances (or blocks of code) in my js file and if I use this, I'd be adding more classes to my html file.  I get what you are saying which is extremely helpful but what I'm looking for is to re-write these 24 blocks of code in my js to a single block of code if that is possible.  And so far with all the help I've

Comment: received, none of it applies to what I'm actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @JorelLokiAmthor calm down, what he is saying is that your code has a hardcode t_2 in it. For your answer to work, that would have to be a variable based on the screenshots_n that was clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a data-target to the screenshot class

`<a class="screenshots_2" data-target="t_2">...</a>`

Then you can do:

```
$('a[class^="screenshots_"]').on('click', function () {
  $('[class^="t_"]').hide(); // You could also add a common .thumb class to target more efficiently
  $('#main-overlay, .' + $(this).data('target')).show();
});'
```

Or, you could be more generic as in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/scottux/0rmgzh7v/

```
$('.screenshot').on('click', function () {
  var idx = $(this).attr('class').match(/_(\d)/)[1];
  $('.thumb').hide();
  $('.t_'+idx).show();
});
```

If you don't want to edit HTML https://jsfiddle.net/scottux/ys4edLvf/7/

```
// bind to all anchors with a class that begins with screenshots_
$('a[class^="screenshots_"]').on('click', function() { 
  // pull the number from this element's class name
  var idx = $(this).attr('class').match(/_(\d)/)[1];
  // hide anything where the class begins with t_
  $('[class^="t_"]').hide();
  // show the corresponding t_ to the number we pulled off this screenshot element
  $('#main-overlay, .t_'+idx).show(); 
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I added a fiddle to my original post - I'm not looking to add more stuff to my html file if I do not have too...

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to have a common class for the respective **a** tag and the **t_#** element combination

HTML:

Your links for View Screenshots should something like this

```
<a class="screenshots t_22" href="#" title="View Screenshots"></a>
```

And your divs should have the toHide class, **followed** by the existing t_# class

```
<div class="toHide t_22">
    ...
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('a.screenshots').click(function() {
    $(".toHide ").hide();
    var clickedClass = this.classList[1];
    $('#main-overlay, .'+ clickedClass).show();

    return false;
});
```

The element.classList returns an array of classes as they appear in the tag. So the first index of the array will return the string **t_#**

The .toHide is used to identify all elements to be hidden. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/ys4edLvf/4/) a fiddle

Comment: Updated the fiddle. Please take a look at the edit in my answer. Used simple lists, its crude, but should give you a hint. 
The html tags can be in any order, as longs as you keep a common class between linked elements.

Comment: @Michael Updated the answer to match your live demo

Comment: I appreciate the help Obsidian but I think I'm going to just leave what I have...